# Installing the certificate chain in Tomcat - Jelastic

Tags: ssl, tomcat7, jelastic

I'm using jelastic to run my application. When I run the sslchecker on the site, I get an error about You may need to install an Intermediate/chain certificate to link it to a trusted root certificate.

In the Jelastic Custom SSL  configuration, I have added the intermediate certificate. I have 2 of those. How can I install both. Right now There is only a option of installing one intermediate certificate. But according to Comodo's installation instuctions I need to install both the certificates. How can I do that.

Comment: Concatenate both intermediate certifcates into a single file. You need to use PEM format (`-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----` and `-----END CERTIFICATE-----`).

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming. See [What topics can I ask about here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Server Fault](http://serverfault.com/) or [Webmaster Stack Exchange](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually root certificate is not needed because it already exists in all web browsers. But sometimes, in case when web-browser is not used for communication, the root certificate should be present. For example when java application communicates with another application or java-client using trusted connection.

In this case instead of intermediate certificate should be uploaded chain of intermediate+root certs.

It is very easy to merge 2 or more certs. Open two intermediate certs using text editor. Copy root cert and past it to end of intermediate as on screenshot.

[image]

Comment: This is what I did. I had to just append the certs according to the hierarchy and that did the trick. Usually it would have been easier because you can import the chain to the keystore and use the keystore. For some reasons I didn't see any examples for using keystore with jeleastic.